# How to make YouCompleteMe work with cgo

Tags: vimscript, plugin-you-complete-me

In C, YouCompleteMe could autocomplte the function if I include the header file in code:

[image]

I want it work like C, when I write Go code and include the C header file in cgo:

[image]

So, how should I config YouCompleteMe? thx.